# jquery get value of ajax load textbox

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have one textbox which load from another file using ajax.
in ajax.php

```
<input type='text' id='ew' name='ew' value='0' class='ew' />
```

in index.php load in

```
<div id='ew1'></div>
```

and script is like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('input.ew').keyup(function(){
                if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0){
                 var ew_ew = $(this).val();
                 alert(ew_ew);

                }
                }); 
         });//ready
```

but i have not get any value

Comment: sorry var ew_ew =$(this).val();

Comment: @NachiketChaudhary, if you are unable to see that alert then open your browser console by pressing F12 and paste this `$('input.ew')` and press enter, tell us what you get

Comment: Where is your ajax request and why do you assign an event on document event instead of ajax success event?

Comment: can you add your ajax method?

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that you successfully included jQuery into your page and try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('.ew').keyup(function(){
                if(!isNaN($(this).val()) && $(this).val().length!=0){
                 var ew_ew = $(this).val();
                 alert(ew_ew);

                }
                }); 
         });//ready
```

Answer (score 0):

Use latest jquery that support jquery on() function

```
$(document).on('keyup','.ew',function(event){
            value = $( this ).val();
            if(!isNaN(value) && value.length!=0){
             var ew_ew = value;
             alert(ew_ew);
            }       
        });
```